# Overlay a smaller image at mouse pointer onto a PictureBox

Tags: c#, winforms, overlay

I'm just starting to develop the Winforms GUI for a C# application and was wondering if the following was possible?

I wish to display a large image in a Picture Box (easily done) and then have a second smaller image overlay onto the large image at the mouse position, when the mouse pointer is over the larger image. If possible I would like the overlay image to be partially transparent.

As the GUI design is at an early stage I can change it to WPF if this would make what I'm asking any easier.

Many thanks,

Andy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's a one-liner in Winforms, just change the PictureBox.Cursor property:

```
 pictureBox1.Cursor = new Cursor(new MemoryStream(Properties.Resources.ExampleCursor));
```

If you need an arbitrary image then you need to convert the bitmap to a cursor.  A little helper function to do it:

```
using System.Reflection;
...
    private static Cursor CursorFromBitmap(Bitmap bmp) {
        var hicon = bmp.GetHicon();
        var cursor = new Cursor(hicon);
        var fi = typeof(Cursor).GetField("ownHandle", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
        fi.SetValue(cursor, true);
        return cursor;
    }
```

With some reflection trickery to avoid having to keep track of the handle and destroy it explicitly.  Use it like this:

```
 pictureBox1.Cursor = CursorFromBitmap(Properties.Resources.ExampleImage);
```

Answer (score 2):

This would be trivial in WPF; just make a second `<Image>` in a `<Canvas>`.

In WinForms, you would need to handle the PictureBox's `Paint` event and draw the image yourself.